# Ecommerce platform

Tags: web-apps, ecommerce

I'm searching for an e-commerce platform that have a good SEO and work fine on mobile devices for a small business.

I did a little search and found Magento and WooCommerce. But I heard that Magento is too complex and slowly. WooCommerce I heard that is difficult to scale WordPress if things get big.

I'm accepting another suggestions free and paid. Would be nice if someone who use/used one of these or both could show an opinion.

Comment: What features do you need? Ecommerce for a small business could be anything … do you want to run a web shop? Product variants? Import of product data? etc.

Answer (score 1):

We created many [Nopcommerce](https://www.nopcommerce.com/) websites for big and complex ecommerce needs

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to consider a hosted system and don't want the hasle of having to set things up / maintain the code, then https://www.shopify.co.uk/ is well respected and worth looking at.

https://solidus.io/ is another open source system to consider should the hosted path not be right for you.